# Display a array of values in a single view in android

Tags: android

**Is there any android library to handle this**

[image]

1. *Above image is a singe view*
2. *There should be one view for which I pass array of values like city above*

Comment: you don't need a library, just concatenate your list or array into a single element and display it in the view

Comment: that "library" is `android.text.TextUtils` class

Answer (score 2):

You can try some thing like this , I don't think library is needed

```
 private String getTextToShow(String[] list){

    String text="";

    if(list==null||list.length==0){
        text="No items";
    }else if(list.length==1){
        text=list[0];
    }else if(list.length==2){
        text=list[0]+", "+list[1];
    }else {
        text=list[0]+list[1]+ "+ " +(list.length-2)+" more";
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an additional library for this specific task, just concatenate the array elements or list into a single element and display it int the view. An example is given below

```
public void setView(ArrayList<String> elements){

    String result="";

    for(String element: elements){
         result=result + " " + elements;
    }

    textview.setText(result);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method which returns a String to bind in the view

```
private String buildString(ArrayList<String> list, int count) {
        StringBuilder ch = new StringBuilder();
        if (count <= list.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ch.append(list.get(i)).append(",");
            }
            return ch.replace(ch.lastIndexOf(","), ch.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, String.format("+ %d more", list.size() - count)).toString();
        } else {
            for (String s : list) {
                ch.append(s).append(",");
            }
            return ch.substring(0, ch.length() - 1);

        }
    }
```